# C# - Could anyone help me with a text box?

Tags: c#, winforms

What do I have to put in the private void textbox to make a user enter a amount and that amount will be applied to where await Connection.SendToServerAsync(2700, 790); is now. so let's say a user enters 2000, 8 in the texbox, then the (2700,790) has to change to (2000, 8)

```
namespace Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : ExtensionForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int repeat = 5;

            for (int i = 0; i <= repeat; i++)
            {
                await Connection.SendToServerAsync(2700, 790);
                await Connection.SendToServerAsync(3745);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I got this as a answer:

You can get the textbox value using TextBox.Text.
It comes as a string, so you have to convert to int. You can do that using one of the following:
Int.Parse
Convert.ToInt32
With the converted value you can just call the methods with the new values when the button is clicked.

Could anyone show me how it's done by copying my code?

Comment: Sorry, your question show that you not even tried anything And asking us do your job. Did you try to call `int.Parse` or `ConvertToInt32`? Show what did you try

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a `textBox1_TextChanged()` event

a dirty way could be the following

```
   private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int repeat = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i <= repeat; i++)
        {                
            await Connection.SendToServerAsync(2700, Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text); // <--|use the integer value to which textBox1 value can be cast to
            await Connection.SendToServerAsync(3745);
        }
    }
```

while a more robust way would check the possibility of actually casting the textBox1 value to an integer before going on:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int repeat = 5;
        int amount;

        if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out amount)) // <--| go on only if textBox1 input value can be cast into an integer
            for (int i = 0; i <= repeat; i++)
            {                
                await Connection.SendToServerAsync(2700, amount); // <--| use the "amount" integer value read from textBox1
                await Connection.SendToServerAsync(3745);
            }
    }
```

Comment: @Misgracious, did you get through it?